# How to add a TIF raster layer programmatically?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, linux

This is my code whenever i try to load .tif image it shows layer is not valid,`QgsRasterLayer` always return invalid layer (I am using linux 12.04).

```
QString myFileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("OpenFile"),"/home/ravi",tr("*.tiff"));
std::cout<<"File Name:"<<myFileName.toStdString();
QFileInfo myRasterFileInfo(myFileName);
QgsRasterLayer * mypLayer = new QgsRasterLayer(myRasterFileInfo.filePath(),
myRasterFileInfo.completeBaseName());
if (mypLayer->isValid())
{
   qDebug("Layer is valid");
}
else
{
   qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
   return;
}
```